# How to create multisite in Craft CMS v3?

Tags: localization, craft3, multi-site

I am looking to create multisite in Craft 3. Is there any way to create multisite in Craft?

Comment: Craft 3 enables the multisite feature by default, you can create a new site in settings->sites

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a very general question. Take a look at the following resources as a starting point:

- [Managing Multiple Sites in Craft 3 – Sites and Localization](https://straightupcraft.com/events/managing-multiple-sites-in-craft-3-sites-and-localization) - Straight Up Craft
- [Using Craft CMS Multi-Site](https://mijingo.com/lessons/craft-3-multi-site/) - Mijingo